# How can I detect user is inactive for 5 seconds in order to assign session key?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement the following scenario for the web-page. If the user is inactive 5 seconds, log-out the user. I have request.session['islogin'], I want to re-assing this session key to the False after user is inactive for 5 seconds. I have tried to use decorators but after few codes, I have not figure out what I should write next so that my code will detect inactive users. Therefore, I have question "How can I detect user is inactive for 5 seconds in order to assign session key, isLogin, to the False ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make middleware for that

**middleware.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth

class AutoLogout:
  def process_request(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated() :
      #Can't log out if not logged in
      return

    try:
      if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
        auth.logout(request)
        del request.session['last_touch']
        return
    except KeyError:
      pass

    request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
```

In your settings, add this in your middleware_classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    .................
    'app_name.middleware.AutoLogout',
]

and this:

# Auto logout delay in minutes
AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY = 60 #this is equivalent for 1 hour
```

Comment: Do I need/add some settings to the Settings file?